# Is Rudin's proof of the inverse function theorem correct?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

This question concerns the proof of the inverse function theorem found in Walter Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (3rd ed.).It defines for each $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$\phi(x)=x+A^{-1}(y-f(x))$$

where $A$ is the matrix of the differential of $f$ at $a$. it shows that
$$|\phi(x) - \phi(z)| \leq \dfrac{1}{2}|x-z|$$
on some open ball centered on a such that $|f'(x)-A|< \lambda = (2|A^{-1}|)^{-1}$. Hence it states that it has at most one fixed point in $U$, so that $f(x) = y$ for at most one $x$ and $U$, so $f$ will be bijective in $U.$ For me this is not clear, as you used the contraction principle here, since $U$ is open, and it is not clear with what you have so far that $\phi(U) \subset U$?

Comment: The ${1 \over 2}$ means the iterates cannot go far from the starting point.

Comment: do you mean that here you did not directly apply the contraction principle? But how will you get the fixed point? Iterating inequality? but it is not necessary to know that $\phi(U) \subset U$?

Comment: Apply the iteration an infinite number of times and compute the maximum distance it can go from the starting point.

Comment: I can't understand what you want to do, for me it doesn't make sense to use fixed point in this situation, but I think I found a way to justify that $f$ is bijective in $U$. from the relation $|\phi(x) - \phi(z)| \leq \dfrac{1}{2}|x-z|$ it is possible to arrive at that $|f(x) - f(z)| \geq \lambda|x-z|$, hence f will be injective in $U$. Maybe you don't really need to do Fixed Point Theorem in this part.

Comment: Ignore my comments above, I was thinking a little further ahead in the proof. There is less to the statement that you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi$ is defined everywhere and $\phi(x) = x$ **iff** $f(x) = y$.

Rudin states that there is '**at most** one fixed point in $U$'.

If there were two distinct fixed points $u_1,u_2 \in U$ then $\phi(u_k) = u_k$ and the contraction shows that $u_1=u_2$, a contradiction. Hence there is at most one fixed point in $U$ and hence there is at most one $x \in U$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: Now maybe I understand, after that he makes a fixed point argument to show that $f(U)=V$ is open, on a closed ball $B$ inside $U$. There he gets a single fixed point for $\phi$ inside that ball, as this ball is inside $U$, this fixed point is unique in $U$. So I think you can consider $\phi: f^{-1}(V)\cap U \rightarrow V$, it will be a bijection between open. Is that correct?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. I am not a fan of Rudin's proof style in general, but he is fairly explicit here. He shows directly that $\phi$ maps $\overline{B}$ into $\overline{B}$.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there is something wrong I would like to correct it.

Comment: How? I didn't downvote, it was someone else. I perfectly understood your answer.

Comment: @Ilovemath Some folks down vote without leaving a reason.